# Starter ideas to build a video player for browser without HTML5video tag

Tags: browser, video-streaming, html5-video, multimedia

I want to build a video player for my web application. But I do not want to use the existing HTML5 Video tag as I want this hard path to be a learning experience for me. I want to do it from scratch and experience every bit of experience.

But I do not know where to start from. Wherever I search and go, I find only people using HTML5Video tag. But as I said earlier I don't want to use it.
Can some one give me ideas how to start this project ? basic ideas of how to run a video in browser and what I should read to get started. Even any links would be helpful.

Comment: The ONLY way to play video in a browser is via the video tag, media sources extensions (which technically use the video tag) or webrtc. So what your looking for may not be a thing.

Comment: Well, canvas may be an option, but that’s crazy.